# Can't get array.splice to work in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the object `words` and a checkbox which should hide a specific element from this object, but I cannot get it work.

```
<body ng-controller="ArrController">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="hide"> {{kc}} 
    {{words}}
</body>
```

The `ArrController`:

```
app.controller('ArrController', function ($scope, $http) {

 $scope.hide = false;

 $http.get('array.json').success(function(data) {
    var keyword = 'lol';
     $scope.words = data.unsorted_arr;
   $scope.$watch('hide', function () {
        if ($scope.hide == true) {
            var remove = function() { 
                $scope.words.splice(keyword, 1);     
            }
            $scope.kc = 'hidden';
        } else {
            $scope.kc = 'not hidden';
            $scope.words = data.unsorted_arr;
        }
    });

 });
});
```

The file `array.json` contains data for `words`:

```
{"unsorted_arr":{"gonna":3,"lol":114,"wouldn":2,"know":6,"lowkey":2,"man":5}}
```

The `kc` modifies according to the checkbox status, but the `words` stays the same.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I can't really follow the flow of the watch.. If $scope.hide == true, set a variable to a function. But I dont see where it is called

Comment: @Fraction Yes, that was a mistake. Modified that line with `var remove = $scope.words.splice(keyword, 1);` as someone mentioned below, but the it still not working  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice is for removing something in an array, and it takes in two integers as parameters.

Since you have an object, just use delete:

```
delete $scope.words[keyword];
```

By doing, $scope.words = data.unsorted_arr, the two variables refer to the same object so deleting something from $scope.words will delete it from data.unsorted_arr.

Keep a reference to it so you can repopulate it later:

```
var word = $scope.words[keyword];
...
delete $scope.words[keyword];
...
$scope.words[keyword] = word;
```

Comment: This is not the same as splice. `delete` creates gaps, while `splice` shifts content to keep a continuous array.

Comment: This seems to be working partialy. It modifies the `kc` and the `words` too, but when I uncheck the checkbox, the `words` remains without the hided element.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are defining a function for removing the element, but the function is never being called.

```
var remove = function() { 
  $scope.words.splice(keyword, 1);     
}
```

you may need to your logic to remove the function (as it doesn't seem to be needed) and replace the of use `splice` with the `delete` statement:

```
$http.get('array.json').success(function(data) {
    var keyword = 'lol';
     $scope.words = data.unsorted_arr;
   $scope.$watch('hide', function () {
        if ($scope.hide == true) {
            delete $scope.words[keyword];
            $scope.kc = 'hidden';
        } else {
            $scope.kc = 'not hidden';
            $scope.words = data.unsorted_arr;
        }
    });

 });
```

Comment: Or at least change it to `var remove = $scope.words.splice(keyword, 1);` if he wants `remove` to contain the deleted element.

Comment: Tried this, but the script does not react at all. The variable `kc` and `words` remain the same. With function (as in my example) the `kc` is modified, the `words` not.

Comment: Oh and also the `keyword` is not correct. You need it to be `..splice($scope.words.indexOf(keyword), 1)`

Comment: @neptune I've updated the answer. Another issue is the use of splice. That won't work with objects, only arrays. I'd suggest using `delete $scope.words[keyword];` to remove an item from the object

Comment: @Filype Trying this, it hide the element as I wanted, but when I uncheck the checkbox (aka it should enter in the `else` part), the `words` remains with the element deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Indexed arrays with associative arrays,

Array.splice is a method of [Indexed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections),
you have a simple [Javascript Object (associative array)](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/1441-javascript-data-structures-the-associative-array.html)...

on POJO you can use the **delete** operator or a simply reassignment to undefined:

```js
var a  = { foo: 'baz' };

delete a['foo'];

var b = ['foo', 'baz'];

b.splice(0, 1)
```